# Iteration in JSON array mule 4 dataweave

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mule4

```
{
  "id": "/",
  "code": "/",
  "typeCode": "CPC",
  "timeStamp": "2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00",
  "childList": [
    {
      "id": "577-1-1",
      "code": "1111",
      "name": "Electronics-1-1",
      "displayName": "Electronics-1-1",
      "active": true,
      "languageCode": "en",
      "typeCode": "CPC",
      "childList": [
        {
          "id": "579-2-1",
          "code": "2222",
          "name": "Calculators-2-1",
          "displayName": "Calculators-2-1",
          "active": true,
          "languageCode": "en",
          "typeCode": "CPC",
          "childList": null
        },
        {
          "id": "509-2-2",
          "code": "3333",
          "name": "Oven-2-2",
          "displayName": "Oven-2-2",
          "active": true,
          "languageCode": "en",
          "typeCode": "CPC",
          "childList": [
            {
              "id": "749-3-1",
              "code": "4444",
              "name": "MicroOven-3-1",
              "displayName": "MicroOven-3-1",
              "active": true,
              "languageCode": "en",
              "typeCode": "CPC",
              "childList": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "549-1-2",
      "code": "5555",
      "name": "Toys, Crafts & Leisure",
      "displayName": "Toys, Crafts & Leisure",
      "active": true,
      "languageCode": "en",
      "typeCode": "CPC",
      "childList": [
        {
          "id": "49674",
          "code": "7605",
          "name": "Pet Supplies",
          "displayName": "Pet Supplies",
          "active": true,
          "languageCode": "en",
          "typeCode": "CPC",
          "childList": [
            {
              "id": "49684",
              "code": "7615",
              "name": "Beds & Houses",
              "displayName": "Beds & Houses",
              "active": true,
              "languageCode": "en",
              "typeCode": "CPC",
              "childList": [
                
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "58782",
      "code": "0100",
      "name": "Fashion (new)",
      "displayName": "Fashion",
      "active": true,
      "languageCode": "en",
      "typeCode": "CPC",
      "childList": [
        {
          "id": "49056",
          "code": "6958",
          "name": "Blazers & Jackets, Etc. - Department",
          "displayName": "Blazers & Jackets, Etc.",
          "active": true,
          "languageCode": "en",
          "typeCode": "CPC",
          "childList": [
            {
              "id": "50851",
              "code": "7837",
              "name": "Dusters PDM Name",
              "displayName": "Dusters PDM Display Name",
              "active": true,
              "languageCode": "en",
              "typeCode": "CPC",
              "childList": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the expected XML is as below - Here the categoryPath has to be noted for the complete address of childElement and has to be grouped under 1st parent childList
We will not know the exact child elements of any array i.e., there can be ‘n’ number of childList inside a childList.
(When the childList value is either empty array [] or null, it is considered as no child elements of that childList.)
How many elements are present in 1st childlist array - those many CategoryList elements has to be formed in xml
Note: here I have just taken 2 elements as an example - but any childlist array can have any number of childlists array inside it.

XML Transformation:

```
<Category CategoryId="${childList.code}" CategoryPath="${childList.code}/${childList.childList.code}" Description="${childList.displayName}" ShortDescription="${childList.name}">
    <Extn ExtnSyncTS="${headers.timeStamp}"/>
</Category>
```

Expected XML:

```
<CategoryListArray>
<CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="1111" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/1111" Description="Electronics-1-1" ShortDescription="Electronics-1-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="2222" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/1111/2222" Description="Calculators-2-1" ShortDescription="Calculators-2-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="3333" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/1111/3333" Description="Oven-2-2" ShortDescription="Oven-2-2">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="4444" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/1111/3333/4444" Description="MicroOven-3-1" ShortDescription="MicroOven-3-1">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
</CategoryList>
<CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="5555" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/5555" Description="Toys, Crafts & Leisure" ShortDescription="Toys, Crafts & Leisure">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="7605" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/5555/7605" Description="Pet Supplies" ShortDescription="Pet Supplies">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="7615" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/5555/7605/7615" Description="Beds & Houses" ShortDescription="Beds & Houses">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
</CategoryList>
<CategoryList>
    <Category CategoryId="0100" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/0100" Description="Fashion" ShortDescription="Fashion (new)">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="6958" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/0100/6958" Description="Blazers & Jackets, Etc." ShortDescription="Blazers & Jackets, Etc. - Department">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="7837" CategoryPath="/DefaultText/0100/6958/7837" Description="Dusters PDM Display Name" ShortDescription="Dusters PDM Name">
        <Extn ExtnSyncTS="2021-11-16T17:00:00-06:00"/>
    </Category>
</CategoryList>
</CategoryListArray>
```

Comment: @aled Created new question

Comment: Do you have a working script for the case without null childLists? If so please share as part of the question.

Comment: the same as posted by you in previous question, works without null childlists

Comment: Then you should add it to the question. Questions and answers should be self contained.

Comment: `<Category CategoryId="2222" CategoryPath="1111/2222" Description="Calculators-2-1" ShortDescription="Calculators-2-1"><Extn ExtnSyncTS=" "/></Category>` why ExtnSyncTS is a space in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a solution using recursion. It might be a bit confusing, I have put explanation in comments within the DW.

```
%dw 2.0
var extnSyncTs = payload.timeStamp

// This is just a small utility function to generate the "CategoryPath"
fun appendToPath(currentPath, pathToAppend) = 
    if(isEmpty(currentPath)) pathToAppend
    else currentPath ++ "/" ++ pathToAppend

/*
* This function will take one object from the child list array 
* and return corresponding XML Category object  
*/
fun childListElementToCategory(childListElement, rootPath='') = 
    {
        Category @(
            CategoryId: childListElement.code,
            CategoryPath: rootPath appendToPath childListElement.code,
            Description: childListElement.displayName,
            ShortDescription: childListElement.name
        ): {
            Extn @(ExtnSyncTS: extnSyncTs): null
        }
    }

/**
* This is a tricky one. It accepts the childList array then uses the above
* function to get the Category element for each of the chileList element. It 
* uses recurssion to call itself if there are more childList in any element 
* of the passed childList. The rootPath element is to retain the path from 
* the parent childList element. 
*/

fun childListToCategoryList(childList, rootPath='') = 
    childList map ((childListElement) -> 
        {
            (childListElementToCategory(childListElement, rootPath)),
            (childListToCategoryList(childListElement.childList, rootPath appendToPath childListElement.code)) 
        }
    )
output application/xml
---
CategoryListArray: {
    CategoryList: (childListToCategoryList(payload.childList))
}
```

Comment: thank you for the above.. just had a doubt, in CategoryPath i need to add few default values also like <CategoryPath: /defaultText/2039/6975>... if i try to define a variable pathText=/defaultText/ and add to the code.. <CategoryPath: pathText++rootPath appendToPath childListElement.code>... for 1st childList - im getting 2 slashes.. , like CategoryPath: ./defaultText//2039.., whereas for others it is fine..

Comment: Can you define the variable without the trailing slash, like `variable pathText=/defaultText`? and not `variable pathText=/defaultText/`

Comment: If not then you can just add another simple condition in the `appendToPath` method like this `else if (currentPath endsWith "/") currentPath ++ pathToAppend` after the first if